# A4 is a normal subgroup of A5

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

The problem is that: How to check, if $A_{4}$ is normal (or not) subgroup of $A_{5}$? We know that $|A_{5}|=60$ - i suppose that we shouldn't find all left and right conjugate classes, because it's a bit tough job, anyway.

How can i cope with it?

Comment: Isn't $A_5$ a simple group?

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal? Do you know that $A_{5}$ has no normal subgroups?

Comment: Yes, according to the fact that it's a simple one, we can state nonexistense of normal subgroups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1,2,5)\in A_5$ and $(1,2,3)\in A_4$ but 
$$(1,2,5)^{-1}(1,2,3)(1,2,5)\notin A_4$$